# Magento wordpress header cms block

Tags: html, wordpress, magento, php

I have a small question. I have included a wordpress blog on my magento shop via the fishpig module. This works great but what I want to include are header options via static cms blocks on the blog. I think I need to adjust something in the phtml of the homepage blog. 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wordpress/homepage.phtml

This is the current code:

```
<div class="page-title blog-title <?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>not-<?php endif; ?>first-page<?php if ($this->isFirstPage() && $this->getTagLine()): ?> with-tagline<?php endif; ?>">
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getBlogTitle()) ?></h1>
</div>
<?php if ($this->isFirstPage() && $this->getTagLine()): ?>
<p class="blog-desc blog-tag-line"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getTagLine()) 
?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="blog-home">
<?php echo $this->getPostListHtml() ?>
</div>
```

I played arount with the following line of code but I cant get it to work:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('example_block')->toHTML();
```

Any solution would be great!!

Thanks..

Comment: Hello @user1773585, welcome on SO. Could you please give a more detailed description of what is not working or where a problem occurs? You code above seems to me, that you are accessing WP-method in a Magento way; what is `$this` in the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display static blocks on the blog page using this code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('example_block')->toHTML();?>
```

But first you need to create a static block in the admin panel. Admin-> Cms-> Static blocks. Then, after you have specified for the static block title, identifier, status and content, you'll need to replace the block identifier in your code to the identifier of the block that you created in the admin.

For example, you have created a block with identifier "blog_header" means the code to show this block on frontend, will be the

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('blog_header')->toHTML();?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Questions here are really being answered:) 
Ive added the below line to the phtml file and created the static CMS BLOCK (identifier “block_header”) in the backend. 
Unfortunately with no luck. 

<div class="block_header <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_header')->toHTML();?>
</div>

Also cleared the cache but magento still doesn’t want to show the CMS block??